# asp.net Repeater - display rows of data in seperate divs

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I am using a Repeater to display rows of data from my SQL Server database. I wish to display each row of my data in separate HTML divs. At the moment it displays all my data (all rows) in the div I have placed the repeater. How do I separate it its seperate divs?

Any suggestions please? :)

```
    <div class="deal-info">
         <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <div class="rptr">
                       <ul>
                          <li><%#Eval("Name")%> </li>
                          <li><%#Eval("ContentType")%> </li>
                          <li><%#Eval("FirstName")%> </li>
                          <li><%#Eval("LastName")%> </li>
                       </ul>
                  </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>     
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap each item in a `<div>`:

```
<li>
  <div><%#Eval("Name")%></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you but that will just separate my "columns", not a whole "row". I got a reply to use <AlternatingItemTemplate>
 which I think will work. Thank you for the reply :)

Comment: @user1371055 This answer does exactly what you described. Perhaps you should edit your question so that the meaning is what you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<AlternatingItemTemplate>`

So:

```
<div class="deal-info">
         <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <div class="rptr">
                       <ul>
                          <li><%#Eval("Name")%> </li>
                          <li><%#Eval("ContentType")%> </li>
                          <li><%#Eval("FirstName")%> </li>
                          <li><%#Eval("LastName")%> </li>
                       </ul>
                  </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
              <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                  <div class="rptr2">
                       <ul>
                          <li><%#Eval("Name")%> </li>
                          <li><%#Eval("ContentType")%> </li>
                          <li><%#Eval("FirstName")%> </li>
                          <li><%#Eval("LastName")%> </li>
                       </ul>
                  </div>
              </AlternatingItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
```